# Passing List / Array of Custom Apex Type from LWC to AuraEnabled method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass back a list of a custom defined Apex from LWC.

Here is some sample code:

```java
public class CustomType{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fooAttribute {get;set;}

    public CustomType(){}
}
```

```java
public class MyController{

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveData(List<CustomType> data)
    {
         System.debug(data);
         return 'foo';
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CustomType> getData()
    {
         CustomType t = new CustomType();
         t.fooAttribute = 'foo';

         return new List<CustomType>{t};
    }
}
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.getData';
import saveData from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.saveData';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    apexData;

    connectedCallback(){
        getData()
        .then(result => {
            this.apexData = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // this.error = error;
        });
    }

    callApex(){
        saveData({data: this.apexData})
        .then(result => {
            //TODO
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

Now when I try to call `saveData` I get a 500 internal server error. But, if I switch everything to single instances of `CustomType`, not a list, this works correctly.

Is it documented somewhere that you cannot pass lists of Custom Apex types?

Comment: I can't find any documentation around how Apex handles type parsing from lwc in general.

Just curious, what happens if you change it to Object[] and then use type casting to convert it to CustomType? You could also probably change it to Object and use `JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(data),List<CustomType>.class)` to get what you want

Comment: @stackasaur yeah, that definitely seems to work better in some ways than `@AuraEnabled` serialization. But it's a little sad to have all of your apex methods return String and have boilerplate serialization code thorough-out it all.

Comment: @stackasaur I dont disagree with your suggestion, I was just hoping to avoid going down the JSON serialize / deserialize route.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the list, you could pass it as a JSON string. -

```
callApex(){
        saveData({data: JSON.stringify(this.apexData)})
        .then(result => {
            //TODO
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

And deserialize it custom apex type in apex

```
  @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveData(String data)
    {
         List<CustomType> customRecs = (List<CustomType>)JSON.deserialize(data,CustomType.class)
         System.debug(customRecs);
         return 'foo';
    }
```

I tried your whole code and it's working perfectly fine for me. Just make sure the user's profile who is trying to run the component has access to the **Mycontroller** apex class.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

I was able to reproduce the error after removing the apex class permission from the profile.

Comment: I appreciate that this does work, however as stated in a comment above, I want to understand why the way I have outlined throws an error.

Comment: @BryanAnderson, can you share the wrapper

Comment: it's in my original post

Comment: @BryanAnderson, check updated answer

Comment: Can you show the Chrome Console output of it working without passing it as a String and doing JSON deserialization.

Comment: I have added the screenshots